# How to display activerecord validations within a lightbox after submitting a form using rails 2.3.15

Tags: activerecord, lightbox, ruby-on-rails-2

I am having rails 2.3.15 application and using ibox for displaying content within lightbox.

I am having a form which is being displayed within a lightbox. On submitting the content, I need to display the activerecord errors (if any) within the same lightbox.

But, as of now, after submitting form, it is displaying the form along with errors in a new page instead of displaying it within a lightbox.

Can anyone please suggest me that, how I can get that content into the lightbox.

Thanks in advance.

K. Subrahmanyam.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with various ways to accomplish the above requirement. But, finally I ended up with an ajax request for submitting the form content.